# toggeling with case when -SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to toggle the activate column in my table; I think it can be done with case statement! I have tried following but apparently it does not work and there is a syntax problem; could you please let me know if it can be done with one statement like the following:

```
update likes l case when active = 1 then set active=0 else set active=1 end where l.uuid=11 and l.scene_id=2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try syntax like

```
update likes SET
active = case when active = 1 then 0 else 1 end 
where uuid=11 and scene_id=2;
```

Comment: You just barely beat me to it (+1) for speed

Comment: same here! was just about to submit

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `MySql`, you could also do the following:

```
update likes 
set active = !active 
where uuid=11 and scene_id=2;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fc9e/1)